# Where the Memory is Leaking because showing leakage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, instruments

In my Code showing 2 places memory leakage please see and Help me.

1.FIRST

```
UIButton *push = (UIButton *)sender;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[push currentTitle]];
NSArray *chunks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[stringcomponentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]];
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:chunks];
(NSMutableArray *list;)
[chunks release];
```

2.SECOND

Here is The Source Code First

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www/absdf.com/myXML.xml"];
self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
[parser release];
[url release];
[pool drain];
```

while i am excuting this code and with this Instruments Tools on line number : 2 show memory leakage with heaviest backtraces.
So please let know the Reason .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers your pool should be released

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

//... then
[pool release];
```

Comment: @Bunts whenever you used "new" you should use "release" too

Comment: but i used drain thats why this problem going on

Comment: use release instead of drain and see if this solves that part

Comment: Thanks a Lot ..... solved. please can you describe me the Difference between drain and release.?

Comment: Drain will drain the pool, but it will not release the pool object itself, the pool object will leak its reference, instead release will realease and drain the pool , please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks but First One till now Problem OK the Condition is I am using NSMutableArray (list) for storing two NSString it is initialize with NSArray because when i am using this function it return NSArray-->NSArray *chunks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[stringcomponentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]]; and Every time when i click on button new value comes from NSArray and initialize NSMutableArray.

Comment: where do you release (NSMutableArray *list;)? also make sure that you dont allocate list more than one time, for example its possible that you will need to release list before reallocating like so, 

[list release];
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:chunks];

Comment: yes it is but what will happen when the button click and list release without initialize.?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:chunks];` is never released.

Comment: but i release it ViewDidUnload like self.list = nil; and in -(void)dealloc like [list release];

Answer (score 0):

```
self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

`alloc/init` returns a `retained` object, and if you your `parser` property is declared with `retain` attribute, then you are over retaining it. It should be:

```
 self.parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
```

P.S. Make sure you are doing proper memory management to your `list` instance variable. Just to be sure you better use properties.

Comment: `alloc/init` does not return an autoreleased object. It returns an object with releaseCount = 1.

Comment: ups.. you're right, my though was it should be autoreleased :P

Comment: I never used property with NSXMLParser. Only create it in the single functions and using it .

Answer (score 0):

1. list should be release somewhere, maybe in dealloc

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {
      [list release];
      [super dealloc];
   }
   ```
2. `parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];`

or

```
NSXMLParser *tempParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.parser = tempParser;
[tempParser release];
```

Comment: I used only tempParser and another parser is there.